# Are virtual keyboards supported for every supported platform?

Tags: mrtk

I was wondering what the current cross platform solution for a virtual Keyboard in the new MRTK v2 RC1 is? The old MRTK had the Unity built keyboard. The current keyboard examples only mentions the TouchScreenKeyboard class and I guess that's primarily for HL2. It definitely does not work when running Unity with the attached Mixed Reality Portal.

https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/mrtk_release/Documentation/README_SystemKeyboard.md

Answer (score 0):

You are correct -- MRTK RC1 does not include a built-in keyboard, but instead invokes Unity's [TouchScreenKeyboard](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard.html), which currently supports iOS, Android, and Windows UWP.

In Windows UWP, this will bring up the system keyboard on HoloLens 2 as well as in Windows Mixed Reality, when the project is compiled. For testing in editor, you will not see a system keyboard show up. For HoloLens 1, I have not yet tested whether `TouchScreenKeyboard.Show` brings up the system keyboard.

Comment: Do you know what this has been tested with? What about Oculus Go? Can I assume it works well with the Unity InputFields and TMP InputFields?